# Mosquitto on EC2 with TLS

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, mqtt

## Problem

I want to setup my MQTT broker on an AWS EC2 instance and connect to it with TLS.

I have the instance running and I can connect (pub/sub) to Mosquitto from my local machine successfully with vanilla unencrypted MQTT. When using TSL, I get the error `tlsv1 alert unknown ca`.

After many hours of reading and trying different tutorials and examples, I still can't figure this out. Here's what I did and in my (limited) understanding of certificates and encryption should work:

## What I tried

Let's say my EC2 instance is available at host `ec2-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com` and IP `54.1.1.1`. My local network's IP is `192.77.77.77`.

SSH into EC2 and generate certificates [using OwnTracks's `generate-CA.sh`](https://github.com/owntracks/tools/blob/master/TLS/generate-CA.sh) in a directory `~/iot`. I generate the certs issuuing

`HOSTLIST="ec2-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com" IPLIST="54.1.1.1" bash ./generate-CA.sh ec2-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

Certificate generation results in a bunch of files, namely

`ca.crt  ca.key  ca.srl  ec2-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com.crt  ec2-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com.csr  ec2-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com.key`

Now I'm ready to configure my broker with `mqtt.conf`:

```
# mosquitto.conf
listener 8883
pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid
persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/
cafile ./ca.crt
certfile ./ec2-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com.crt
keyfile ./ec2-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com.key
```

Time to start the broker with `mosquitto -c mqtt.conf`.

In order to sub to the broker, I copy the content of `ca.crt` to my laptop and run `mosquitto_sub -h ec2-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com -p 8883 --cafile ca.crt -t +`.

## Resulting error

What I get on the subscriber side is

```
Error: A TLS error occurred.
```

The server does realize there is a connection attempt happening but reacts with

```
1475320985: New connection from 192.77.77.77 on port 8883.
1475320986: OpenSSL Error: error:14094418:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert unknown ca
1475320986: OpenSSL Error: error:140940E5:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:ssl handshake failure
1475320986: Socket error on client , disconnecting.
```

I've tried following guides step by step like [this very good one](http://rockingdlabs.dunmire.org/exercises-experiments/ssl-client-certs-to-secure-mqtt) or [this one](https://primalcortex.wordpress.com/2016/03/31/mqtt-mosquitto-broker-with-ssltls-transport-security/) but to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I was writing this down, I realized that in my last attempt (which followed all the steps lined out above), I forgot to copy the `ca.crt` file to the client before trying to subscribe it to the broker.

With the wrong `ca.crt` file installed on the client (a different one from a previous attempt), the above `unknown ca` error makes a lot of sense. After copying the file to the client, it successfully connected with TLS to the broker on EC2.

I figured I'd still post the question as it took me some hours to figure all the details in all the steps out, and it might come in handy for others running into similar problems.

Comment: thanks alot , I was stuck on same problem with openssl